# Can enums hold classes as members?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, enums

I'm trying to add classes to an `enum`, but I can't find a way to make it work.

I have a "main" class (let's call it `Product`) which should hold some other different classes, that hold different properties, under a single `enum` (let's call it `Property`). The `Property` `enum` should contain multiple different classes which fall under the `Product` class, so that I can use one of them, depending on which product is in question. However, when I try to include a class under an `enum`, it's not being recognized as a class at all.

Is there way to include classes as members under an `enum`?

Comment: Even if they could (which they don't), how would you expect to use them? maybe you just want a switch statement, or if you really need you could use `Dictionary<enum,interface>` or a factory pattern, or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this not what enums are build for.
Enums are like primitve classes (like `int`) and should be used in this way.

Comment: I could have wrote that, can you please elaborate, show alternatives, and make this a little more well, qualitative

Comment: Its a closed question. I dont know exactly what you like to do, but I can answer the question of the title. Can you provide a code-example for us?

Answer (score 1):

There is not.

See [enum-Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any
>   integral numeric type.

An enum type is always numeric.